# Is there any way to run others apps in my Android app's layout?

Tags: android

I know it may sound weird but i was wondering for few days that can i launch any `android app` in my `android app's layout`? I searched in the google but couldn't find any answer.I know that  app's have ability to send the user to another app based on an "action" it would like to perform.But i would like to know can i run the app in my app's layout??Suppose i have an app that has a layout called activity_main and now i want to replace the activity_main's layout with the app i want to call so that the called app is running inside my app.Thanks in advance to anyone who can clear my doubt??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can i launch any android app in my android app's layout?

No.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run any Android App inside your App. 
But, you can run a WebApp [thats adaptive designed] inside your Android App.